# Error 502 Bad Gateway Nginx and Celery Workers

Tags: nginx, celery, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am trying to run a docker-compose with Nginx, Celery, RabbitMQ and Django in a Gunicorn server. The application runs fine without the Nginx, but in production I need the Nginx to serve the static files, and getting an `Error 502 Bad Gateway` from Nginx when I add it.

Below is the docker-compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - rabbit
    volumes:
        - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn api.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
    ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:latest


volumes:
  db-data:
```

Below is my Nginx.conf file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what may be causing the issue? Most problems reported on stackoverflow don't deal with proxy servers infront of celery workers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I had to specify the location for all my css files and specify my docker volume in the docker-compose.yml file. Afterwards, everything worked well. Relatively trivial